# nodejs authenticate not working

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am using a nodejs rest api and for authentication, using passport Basic Strategy.

When i send request with authentication the server responds with:

> Unknown authentication strategy "basic"

This is my BasicStrategy:

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(function (userName, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({username: userName}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (!user) return callback(null, false);
        user.checkPassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err)return callback(err);
            if (!isMatch) return callback(null, false);
            return callback(null, user);
        })
    })
}));
```

This is my router:

```
router.get("/",  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), function (req, res) {
    bookModel.find(function (err, books) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json(books);
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            log.error("Internal error (%d): %s", res.statusCode, err.message)
            return res.json({error: "Server error"});
        }
    });
});
```

My client in java okhttp:

```
private static void getBooks() throws IOException
    {
        Request request;
        Response response;
        String credentials = Credentials.basic("Axror", "topsecret");
        System.out.println(credentials);
        request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:1337/api/book/")
            .header("Authorization", credentials)
            .build();
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to initialize passport. You need to:

```
var app = express();
......
......
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you written this?

```
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
```

This is required to use `BasicStrategy`.